# Encrypting boot partition in Linux (RHEL)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, encryption

ALL,

Recently we went through the certification process and there was a finding that an attacker can have an access to the /boot partition.

It was suggested to encrypted the whole hard drive including the /boot partition to mitigate this.

Here is the questions I have:

1. How the password for the boot procedure is generated to decrypt the /boot partition? Do we as a developers/IA team have control to generate it?

The reason for them is that we have a process of duplicating the harddrive after creating the release and putting it into the hard drive. It is also possible that the hard drive can be put into a different machine.

How those situation will be handled? Will the password have to be generated after each copy of the HD? Will the password be copied over with each release and we will end up with the same password for multiple hard drive? Will password be dependent on the hardware it was used to create it or it will be made by some other means?

What are other culprits we should be looking at to see if its feasible or it can't be done because of time/money/process?

Thank you for any pointers you can provide. This is the first time we are going thru this test finding and this one stumbles us.

Answer (score 0):

Chicken and egg problem... Something has to boot first from unencrypted media to decrypt your boot partition... This is one purpose of [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Secure_boot). The boot program is signed, and the machine won't start an unsigned or corrupt boot. Another solution is to boot only from a read-only media (assuming you can keep that safe and enforced).

What is not clear in your question is how attackers can access the `/boot` partition. If they do it by penetrating a running system, no encryption is going to save you. If they do it because they have physical access to the system, then they have plenty of [other attack methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Management_Engine#Claims_that_ME_is_a_backdoor).

For a more in-depth answer see https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: the official testing was performed by removing the hard drive, putting it into another machine and then mounting the /boot partition read-write. Then the tester removed the SELinux switch, put the hard drive back, boot normally and gain "root" access to the system. The "mitigation step" that was provided said - `/boot partition needs to be encrypted to prevent the /boot partition access`. Just trying to follow what was written. Our / partition is encrypted but not the /boot one.

Comment: IMHO if someone can pull that off without anyone noticing, you have a very serious problem. Possible mitigations, 1) locks/badge readers/K9 squad in the server room, 2) mutual overlooking of servers, and quarantine of any server that disappears for more than a couple of seconds or looks tampered with.

Comment: completely agree. But that was done during testing and the official mitigation write-up said `can be mitigated by encrypting /boot partition`. Hence the questions. Also, this was one of the test performed to gain access to the system as `root`. The hard drive was pulled off, put to a different machine, /boot was mounted, SELinux turned off and then the hard drive was put back on allowing to logging in around SELinux restrictions.

Comment: I further understand that there will be a possibility of password hack attacks to mount /boot partition, but at least it will pass further testing.

Comment: Come to think of it, if someone can access the machine and tweak the disk, that person can replace it with a totally different operating system... (or add a small server in the server room...). Preventing physical access is your first line of defense. Good desktop/laptop PCs also have a swtch to detect (and memorize in the BIOS)  the opening of the enclosure).

Comment: we are not talking servers - we are talking a client application which runs on top of RHEL6. Moreover there is no physical connection to any server - all clients connects to some middle-tier in the secure environment who then sends all traffic to the server. But clients are basically un-protected - they can be anywhere at any given time. We do have a function to wipe clean the hard drive, which is irreversible, but this specific test is not about that. I also don't care about some other hard drive - just our software.

Comment: Then use desktops where the chassis can be locked and if possible with a tamper detection switch. AFAIK on the Lenovo desktops using a cable lock also prevents opening the chassis.  I assume that other brand desktops have a similar feature.

Comment: we don't have control over the test bed environment for that specific testing. More over it was done outside of our environment, in a different state. We do have procedure in place in case something happen, but those hackers were doing penetration testing in their own environment.